# Подсчёт количества цифр 1 в числе

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы программа выдавала количество цифр 1, если, к примеру, число является 161511?
Цифр один должно быть 4.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter your number" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Your entered number is " << x << " Calculating the amount of ones in it" << endl;
    int xnum1s = 0;
    while (x)
    {
        x = x / 10;

        if (x <= 1)
        {
            xnum1s++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The amount of numbers 1 in the number is " << xnum1s << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Добавьте код Вашей попытки решения задачи

Comment: Уже поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор остатка от деления:

```
while (x)
    {
        if (x%10 == 1)
            xnum1s++;
        x = x / 10;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Теперь понял.